# What is the relationship between IObservable and ObservableExtensions in Rx?

Tags: c#, rx.net

I read the code of Reactive Extension, then I find this code

```
private readonly IObservable<TSource> _source;
protected override IDisposable Run(IObserver<TResult> observer, IDisposable cancel, Action<IDisposable> setSink)
{
    var sink = new _(this, observer, cancel);
    setSink(sink);
    return _source.SubscribeSafe(sink);
}
```

I find that the method `SubscribeSafe(sink)` is in the class `ObservableExtensions`, and the class isn't implement the interface `IObservable`. Why  the parameter  _source have the member function  `SubscribeSafe`()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the methods in `ObservableExtensions` are extension methods.
You can read about them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx).

Comment: Thank you. It's exactly what I want to know。：)